# How to "press" a button in the inspector tab from script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the inspector tab I see public variables, checkboxes and buttons as a part of some complex script.

How can I use C# to "press" a button/checkbox or set a value to a variable in the inspector tab, without finding and calling the corresponding functions inside this script?

So I want just to trigger the same effect which would happen if I would manually press a button in the inspector tab.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean something like... if you wanted to check the isTrigger box in a collider2D you would do `GetComponent.Collider2D.isTrigger = true;`

Comment: @ryemoss Thanks, but I mean a custom script. In the inspector tab, i can see input fields, checkboxes, and buttons. Can I "click" on the custom script button in the inspector from another script? Or the only way is to call the same function, which will be called if I will manually click the checkbox?

Comment: @Rumata Correct, you would need to call the method that the buttons click is calling. For example, lets say your button is 'Generate Terrain' - that buttons method body in turn calls `GenerateTerrain(); CleanUp();` - your script would then need to call that sequence of events. For things like checkboxes, that's a matter of setting a value of a property, etc.

Comment: @DeeKayy90 So is it the only way - to call the same functions which the button calls? Can't  I just trigger some "click" event for this button, nothing more, so that the button will call its own functions itself, with no need for me to call them?

Comment: @Rumata Whether it is the only way or not, I am not 100% sure. Could there be a way to programmatically click a button in the inspector? Possibly. I would recommend you call the functions that are associated with that button, rather than calling the `button.Click` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Button myButton;

myButton.onClick.Invoke();
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly. There is a custom script, and in the inspector tab, I see public input fields, buttons, and checkboxes. Can, for example,  click on a checkbox in the innspector tab using C#? Or the only way is to find out which functions are being called when I'm clicking on the checkbox, and call the same functions?

Answer (score 0):

Inspector shows you the Components of a game object , if you create an empty GameObject You will see the Transform Component Which you can add a reference To that in your Script on another GameObject like `public GameObject nameYouWanted` and then a slot will appears in in the inspector of the GameObject that script is attached to that which named `nameYouWanted` and then you can drop the game object that you created in there.
so far you just created a script on another Gameobject and then created a empty GameObject , in this step you can access the transform Component of Second GameObject by just writing `someVariable = nameYouWanted.transform.position` in start Or update Function in your Script! **JUST LIKE THAT!** 
simple as it is , you can access camera component of mainCamera by writing `public Camera mainCamera` and then access camera components
 
**JUST KEEP IN MIND THAT:**
in case of: 
`public GameObject varName`

**public** is the variables accessibility level 
**GameObject** is Component type 
**varName** is obvious is the variable name

so here is the tricky part for beginners: 
for example i have this components on my Camera

[image: Components]

How can I access for example the LensDistortionBlur variables?
or another one i.e. Frost Component ?

**ANSWER IS:**
You Just have to add a reference to that in Your Script like

```
public LensDistortionBlur LensDistortionBlurEffect;
```

this image is related to glitch effect: 
[image]

you see how monodevelop suggests the components variables to use ???

and then in inspector add the target GameObject in this slot (which contains LensDistortionBlur) , here is the good thing: Just because you specified the LensDistortionBlur  as Component type, script just asks from that gameobject the LensDistortionBlur component and dont uses other ones, then Use that inside of any function that you want,
More Important thing in that is **Component TYPE** which is LensDistortionBlur , Yes you should use the component name that you want to access it , More info is [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/356/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Components.html)

**IN YOUR CASE**
Those bools and variables you mentioned can be accessed by solution that explained above!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a really helpful explanation! However, my question is - is there an alternative to this method?

Imagine, there is a button, and it will call some functions if I click it. So if I will just manually click on it in the inspector -  it will call some functions itself, with no need for me to do anything more than just click on it. So my question is - can I just click on the button using C#?  
  
Can I just trigger some "click" event for this button, nothing more, so that the button will call its own functions itself, with no need for me to call them?

Comment: You know what ? that button you say runs a function , right ? So it is simple . you can reference to that script and then find that function by reference and then run it!